# Swift - Xcode 6 opening signup view from app delegate doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, appdelegate

I want when I open my app, if a certain condition is true, the app to open to a custom SignUpViewController instead of my TabBarViewController.

What I did is in the application function in my app delegate is use the following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        //removed condition for testing
        var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var profileViewController: SignUpViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Registration") as SignUpViewController

        rootViewController?.navigationController?.popToViewController(profileViewController, animated: true) 

        return true

}
```

I have named my ViewController in the storyboard and everything should work fine. but instead of opening to the SingUpViewController the app opens normally to the first tab in my TabBarViewController.

I don't get any crashes it just doesn't show.

Using: pushViewController didn't work either.

My storyboard:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?

**EDIT:**

This is what I write to present the view instead of using nav controller:

I switch out this line:

```
rootViewController?.navigationController?.popToViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
```

With this line:

```
rootViewController?.presentViewController(profileViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I run it, i get a crash on this line:

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Here is an image of the crash:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I am new to Xcode and Swift and iPhone development, here is the console when it crashes:

[image]

From what I can see now it refers to a loginButton from the viewController I am trying to present. I am guessing there is a problem there, ill try and fix it, but if you know what the problem is answer anyways.

**EDIT:**

I can see the problem lies somewhere in the new ViewController. Yet it is referring to something which does not exist.

Here is the code of the new view controller:

```
import UIKit

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func signUpPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    @IBAction func loginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Your "rootViewController" is "UITabBarController", and "UITabBarController" do not have "navigationController".

Comment: You need to add an exception break point and / or show the stack trace. That error message is no use on its own

Comment: @jrturton Very sorry, I am new to iOS development, just found the console log. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rootViewController` is presumably a tab bar controller. This won't have a navigation controller (since it isn't contained in one), so your optional chaining breaks down.

In any case you'd end up with the other tabs showing. I think you want the root view controller to present the sign up controller instead.

Your second problem is because you'll have connected an outlet in your storyboard to something that doesn't exist any more. If you select the SignUpViewController in the storyboard and look at the connections inspector, you should see it, there will be an exclamation mark next to it indicating that it can't be connected. Delete the connection and you should be fine.

Comment: I see. I have tried presenting the view but the app crashes with a signal SIGABRT error on my "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {"
 line.

Comment: Then you're probably doing it wrong :) Can you edit your question to include the code?